# How to return a list of all possible numbers using recursion

Tags: python, list, recursion

I am learning about recursion in python currently but there is this one exercise that I simply cannot figure out in the following code I have two functions and using recursion i print all possible numbers from a given list, but for the life of me I cannot get all the possible numbers into a single list. Any tips on how to do this would really be appreciated.

```
def find_possible_strings(char_set, n):
    k = len(char_set)
    return possible_stringsRec(char_set, "", k, n)


def possible_stringsRec(char_set, prefix, k, n):
    if n == 0:
        print(prefix)
        return

    for i in range(k):
        newPrefix = prefix + char_set[i]
        possible_stringsRec(char_set, newPrefix, k, n - 1)

char_set = ['a','b']
possible_strings = find_possible_strings(char_set, 2)
print(possible_strings)
```

Just to specify I am not simply looking for a solution but rather an actual explanation of how this could be done in python if anyone would be so kind.

I am just getting the result as follows:

```
aa
ab
ba
bb
None
```

and what I want is for all those values to be stored inside a single list
so essentially:

```
['aa', 'ab', 'ba', 'bb']
```

Comment: also if anyone can show me how to post code properly im sure it would help you guys

Comment: highlight your code and press Ctrl + K to format it

Comment: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `results=[]` keyword argument to the `possible_stringsRec` function, and instead of printing out the values within the function, append to the `results` list:

```
def find_possible_strings(char_set, n):
    k = len(char_set)
    return possible_stringsRec(char_set, "", k, n)


def possible_stringsRec(char_set, prefix, k, n, results=[]):
    if n == 0:
        results.append(prefix)
        return

    for i in range(k):
        newPrefix = prefix + char_set[i]
        possible_stringsRec(char_set, newPrefix, k, n - 1)
    return results

char_set = ['a','b']
possible_strings = find_possible_strings(char_set, 2)
print(possible_strings)
```

Output:

```
['aa', 'ab', 'ba', 'bb']
```

The explanation is pretty straightforward: the `results` list starts out as empty when the first function call happens, and whenever a value get appended to it, the value *remains inside* the list for the next function call.

This demonstrates why:

```
def func(lst=[]):
    lst.append(1)
    print(lst)

func()
func()
func()
```

Output:

```
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Thank you so much such a simple solution to something that took me so long. Makes me feel stupid haha